# scroll down shortcut vscode jupyter notebook to see content

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have the following problem:
I am using jupyter notebooks in vscode, and I would like to scroll down in such a window for example to see the whole content of the graph:
[image: scrolling issue]
I would like to do it with a shortcut, but I can't find how to do it.
I also listen for any alternative workaround here.
Thank you !

I tried using the arrow keys but it just moves to the next cell.